# How to disable inetd and sendmail under OpenBSD 5.1?

Tags: openbsd, startup, services

```
# grep '^inetd_flags="' /etc/rc.conf
inetd_flags="NO"                # for normal use: ""
# grep -i 'sendmail_flags="NO"' /etc/rc.conf
sendmail_flags="NO"
#

after a reboot..:
two questions:

# ps -aux | egrep -i "inetd|sendmail"
root      4420  0.0  0.1   452   652 ??  Is     8:10PM    0:00.00 /usr/sbin/inetd
#
```

**QUESTION**: How can I disable inetd, so that it will not start after a reboot? (+how can I disable sendmail correctly?)

Comment: Why do you want to disable sendmail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could delete the symlinks for them in the /etc/rc2.d (or rc3.d) directory. That will stop them from starting up at startup.

`rm /etc/rc2.d/*sendmail* /etc/rc2.d/*inetd*`

Answer (score 2):

@BenjiWiebe: That would be true for Linux. But this is OpenBSD.

If you really want to turn it off properly in the current version of OpenBSD (5.9) edit the file: /etc/rc.conf  Look for the line that starts with smtpd_flags and change it to say: smtpd_flags=NO

You should not do this since the system mails reports of the system's health daily. You will save very very little memory and CPU usage.

My guess is that you don't feel comfortable for other reasons - you don't want to become a spam relay since the standard setup allows a local user to email out to the internet. To only allow local to local mail edit the file /etc/mail/smtpd.conf and change the last line to: accept from local for local

Answer (score 0):

On OpenBSD 5.3 I didn't find any symlinks, it just has one `/etc/rc/` directory, so I edited `/etc/rc` (lines starting with `start_daemon`).